# Does the ternary dot product have any geometric significance?

Tags: geometry, soft-question

Given vectors $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}^n$, define that their ternary dot product $x \cdot y \cdot z$ is the following real number:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_i z_i$$

Recall that the usual (binary) dot product has a lot of geometric meaning. For example the dot product of two vectors is $0$ iff they're orthogonal. My question is: does the ternary dot product have any geometric significance? For example, suppose $x \cdot y \cdot z$ equals $0$. Does this condition have a geometric interpretation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it has a geometric interpretation, that interpretation certainly has to be less obvious. One major setback seems to be, that the *ternary dot product* is NOT invariant under rotations. Consider the example $x,y,z\in\mathbb R^2$ given by
$$
x=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix},\quad y=\begin{pmatrix}\sqrt 2/2\\\sqrt 2/2\end{pmatrix},\quad\text{and }z=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}
$$
which has ternary dot product equal to zero and may be rotated by $\pi/4$ to
$$
x'=\begin{pmatrix}\sqrt 2/2\\\sqrt 2/2\end{pmatrix},\quad y'=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix},\quad\text{and }z'=\begin{pmatrix}-\sqrt 2/2\\\sqrt 2/2\end{pmatrix}
$$
having ternary dot product $\langle x',y',z'\rangle=1/2$.

Comment: Nice observation.

Comment: One idea is that perhaps there exists a variant on the concept of rotation which *does* preserve the ternary product. A rotation matrix can be defined as a matrix $A$ such that $A^TA = I$ and $\mathrm{det} A = 1$. Maybe we can find a variant on the condition $A^T A =I$. No matter what we do, however, this is never going to be euclidean geometry.