# Does there exist a non-identity matrix that preserves the ternary dot product?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, geometry, multilinear-algebra

This is an variant on an [older question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1196736/does-the-ternary-dot-product-have-any-geometric-significance).

Define the ternary dot product

\begin{align*} 
\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n &\rightarrow \mathbb{R} \\ 
x,y,z &\mapsto x \bullet y \bullet z
\end{align*}

as follows:

$$x \bullet y \bullet z = \sum_{i \in n} x_iy_i z_i$$

For example: $$(x_0,x_1) \bullet (y_0,y_1) \bullet (z_0,z_1) = x_0 y_0 z_0 + x_1 y_1 z_1$$

More generally, there's a $k$-ary dot product $$\overbrace{\mathbb{R}^n,\ldots,\mathbb{R}^n}^k \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$ defined in the obvious way.

> **Questions.**
>
> **Q0.** $(k=3)$. Does there exist an $n \geq 0$ together with an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ distinct from $I_n$ satisfying the following identity? $$Ax \bullet Ay \bullet Az = x \bullet y \bullet z$$
>
> **Q1.** $(k=4)$. Does there exist an $n \geq 0$ together with an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ distinct from $I_n$ and $-I_n$ satisfying the following identity? $$Aw \bullet Ax \bullet Ay \bullet Az = w \bullet x \bullet y \bullet z$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes to both.  For $n = 2$, let $A = \pmatrix{0 & 1\cr 1 & 0\cr}$.  Or for general $n$, take any permutation matrix.

Comment: That was quick (:

Comment: The converse is also true, isn't it? Only permutations solve these equations for all vectors.

Comment: @Stefan You could multiply such a matrix by a $k^{\rm th}$ root of unity. Not sure if there are other solutions.

Comment: So if it's real, $-$ a permutation matrix (when $k$ is even).

Comment: But also, if $k$ is even, a permutation matrix with any subset of the $1$'s replaced by $-1$.